# Fix Size ROI for all images in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, roi

I have multiple images and I am using imcrop function to take ROI in image. The problem with imcrop is it gives me different size of ROI on each image. I would like to take ROI of same size for each image. There is a option in imcrop by which I can select size but for that I need to keep my location of ROI fix. I want to fix window size but vary location of window on image. Is there a function available for this functionality in Matlab?

Comment: "same size" in pixels, or in % of image? What is wrong with `myROI = myImage(offsetY + (1:sizeY), offsetX + (1:sizeX));`?

Comment: I would like to use size in pixels. In Imcrop I get a rectangle and I use that rectangle to select ROI on image. But you can resize rectangle in Imcrop. I want rectangle size fix and I should be able to move rectangle on image and select desired ROI.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found the solution for cropping fixed sized window from image (interactively).

```
img = imread('circuit.tif'); %your image
imshow(img);

h = imrect(gca, [75 68 130 112]);
setResizable(h,0)
position = wait(h);
imgc = imcrop(img,position);
figure();
imshow(imgc);
```

Using imrect allows you to set your standard [xmin ymin width height] parameters. Set xmin and ymin to anything (0,0; approximate position) and width and hight to desired values.

Now you can drag your cropping window around the image and double click it when done.

regards,
Piter71

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I do not see a problem with `imcrop`. It takes a rectangle `[xmin ymin width height]` as input. So if you want to keep the size fixed, you have to keep `width` and `height` fixed and change `xmin` and `ymin` which is the top-left corner of the rectangle.

I would like to tell you one more function which can be used i.e. [roipoly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roipoly.html?searchHighlight=roipoly). You give the coordinates of vertices as the input to the function along with image. So if you want a hexagonal ROI, you would give 6 points as input. You then get a binary mask which you can multiply to get your ROI.